# php array of checkboxes

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

In a list of products and next to each I have a checkbox avail[] for each to indicate the availability.

```
$listvals=$_POST['avail'];
$n=count($listvals);

for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['avail']); $i++) {
        $avail= ($listvals[$i]<>'' ? 1 : 0);
    $query_update = "update products set avail=$avail where id ='".$listvals[$i]."'";
    $update = mysql_query($query_update, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

So far I'm fine when it comes to checking the selected products as available using the following update query but when I want to un-select a product (to be marked as not available) it ignores the products because obviously the `$_POST` value is null/zero. How should I handle the array of checkboxes in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to deal with this is to use a hidden form field for each checkbox.

Eg

Replace

```
<input name="avail[<?php echo $product_id?>]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

With

```
<input name="avail[<?php echo $product_id?>]" type="hidden" value="0" />
<input name="avail[<?php echo $product_id?>]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

That way you will definitely get either 0 or 1 returned in your array.  If the check box is ticked, you will get 1.  Otherwise it will default to the value of the hidden field - 0.  Note that this will only work if you are using fixed indexes for the array.  In other words

```
<input name="avail[]" type="hidden" value="0" />
<input name="avail[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Won't work because it will add both options to the array.

*Update: Added this for clarification*

You then to amend your php slightly to something like:

```
$listvals=$_POST['avail'];

foreach($listvals as $product_id => $available) {
    $query_update = "update products set avail=$available where id ='".$product_id."'";
    $update = mysql_query($query_update, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

A possibly simpler method, if you are looking for only the products ticked to be available, is to run another sql script beforehand to set the availability to 0/false/null for everything - esentially make all your products unavailable then re-add the correct ones.

A quick rough and ready version:

```
$listvals=$_POST['avail'];
$n=count($listvals);

/*
 * add this
 */
mysql_query('update products set avail = 0');

for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['avail']); $i++) {
        $avail= ($listvals[$i]<>'' ? 1 : 0);
    $query_update = "update products set avail=$avail where id ='".$listvals[$i]."'";
    $update = mysql_query($query_update, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, I'm getting a hang of it now... The only thing I need to understand better is the part where you say "Note that this will only work if you are using fixed indexes for the array". How do I use fixed indexes?

As for the option of setting them all to null and then updating please read my comment below, under andyb's suggestion.

Comment: Well to be honest, i reckon you probably are anyway in order to determine which records to update.  If your checkbox tags look something like <input type="checkbox" name="avail[<?php echo $product_id ?>]" /> then you should be ok.  It's just if there is nothing inside the square brackets that you will get problems

Comment: Yes, that's how I set the checkboxes values. 
You suggest that I use a secondary array to determine which rows to update?

Comment: You could indeed use that with the second method if you only wanted to update a subset of the records.  The only issue i can see with that is that your products would always need to be ordered by id.  Alternatively you could dump the ids to update in a hidden form field, separate them with a ; (or any other symbol of your choice ;)) and then explode them again after.  If you did want to use the first method, I have updated my answer to give an idea of what you would need to change in the php to use the associative array indexes

Comment: Ooops - think we had a crossed comment there!  I realised after posting the comment that your php implied that you were using the values of the checkboxes rather than the indexes of the array so I updated my answer with the php changes that would be needed.  The idea of dumping a list of ids to update in a hidden form field is still valid tho

Comment: i was using hidden field but my error was that i used it after the field not before it.thanks for you answer

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way, in my opinion, would be to set the availability to `null` for all products wiht the corresponding `id` and then update the availability to `true/1` for the products you do have in the `$_POST`. The alternative to this would need to compare the previously selected products with the newly selected products. From experience, that requires more testing and more code and therefore more that *could* go wrong.

**Edit:**

So, I assume a user can check one or more boxes on an HTML `<form>`, which is submitted to PHP page that processes the form and updates multiple rows in a `products` table (one for each checkbox). So the user checks 4 out of 6 boxes so you update 4 rows out of 6 to `true` or `1`. If on a subsequent page load the user de-selects a product, the PHP page now received 3 *checked* products. The problem is how to know which one was de-selected since it is not in the `$_POST`. Therefore the easiest solution is to update the `products` table and set the `avail` to `null` for all the products as a separate query first and then execute the existing code you have in the question to update only the checked products to `true` again.

**Edit2:** Right, so assuming you are potentially updating up to 40 products at a time, how about just `null`ing whatever 40 are on the page that is being submitted?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your approach with the comparsion, would a simple example be possible?

Comment: Yes, this is how its SUPPOSED to work. I cant set all values to null though because I have around 400 products in my database and they are displayed in pages of 40, setting them all to 0/null and then updating only the ones that I've selected would cause problems with the rest of the products.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a JavaScript associative array with id and status, which you can modify on each change and post it back.
2. Otherwise use hidden fields to set values (hidden input fields with all values set to 1 if all selected by default, when user unchecked any row, make the hidden input value to 0)
3. you can get the same array what you used to display the list of products on server side and loop it to compare which are removed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your 2nd approach, would a simple example be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well this chosen answer did not suit my needs because of reasons I won't go into but what worked for my purposes is this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="'.$x.'" name="sent[]" />
```

Then within the loop that checks a bunch of stuff I just ask:

```
if (in_array ($x, $thesentarray)) { /* Now I know x is one of the checked */ }
```

So that I know the particular item in question has been checked when dealing with each item within the loop Prior to that I make sure that any are checked and also if only one is checked I convert it into an array before hand

Hope this answer helps someone