# Map dynamic array of checkboxes without index

Tags: php, jquery, html, dom

This question builds further on the question asked here: [How to map dynamic array of input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043116/how-to-map-dynamic-array-of-input-fields) .

I have a dynamic set of rows with each it's own input fields. These rows can be dynamically added to the DOM, so I have to use input arrays without an index ( eg fieldname[] instead of fieldname[1] etc).

The problem occurs when I use checkboxes in these rows. Since checkboxes are not submitted when they are not checked, I see no way of knowing which submitted checkbox belongs to which row values.

Example of my form:

```
<form>
<div class="row">
     <input type="text" name="product[]">
     <input type="text" name="qty[]"> 
     <input type="checkbox" name="projectline[]"> 
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="product[]">
    <input type="text" name="qty[]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="projectline[]"> 
</div>
<div class="row">
     <input type="text" name="product[]">
     <input type="text" name="qty[]">
     <input type="checkbox" name="projectline[]"> 
</div>
</form>
```

I found an answer to a similar problem here: [php array of checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582355/php-array-of-checkboxes) , but the answer obviously only applies to arrays with an index.

What is the best approach here?

**EDIT :**

I also check the form for errors server-side and redirect it back if it is faulty, So I need to be able to 'reconstruct' the form based on the submitted values.

Comment: Would it be possible to keep a running count of how many you have and assign them indexes as they're put in?

Comment: I agree with QPaysTaxes. That seems to make the most sense.

Comment: I can probably work that in via javascript, but was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Just give them a value... `<input type="checkbox" name="projectline[]" value="<index, id, ...>" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up assigning an index number to each of the rows, generating a new random id each time a row is added. I used jQuery for the clone functions and event binding.

Below is my complete solution.

This is my original form:

```
<form>
<div class="row">
 <input type="text" name="product[0]">
 <input type="text" name="qty[0]"> 
 <input type="checkbox" name="projectline[0]"> 
</div>
</form>
```

I have a template row that I use to make clones of:

```
<div id="templaterow">
 <input type="text" name="product[%%index%%]">
 <input type="text" name="qty[%%index%%]">
 <input type="checkbox" name="projectline[%%index%%]"> 
</div>
```

A button to clone the row:

```
<button id="addrow" value="add new row"/>
```

And a function bound to the button:

```
$('#addrow').on('click',function()
{
    //template row is cloned and given the right attributes:
    var clone = $('#templaterow').clone(true, true);
    $('.row').last().after(clone);
    clone.addClass('row').removeAttr('id');

    // the %%index%% placeholder is replaced by a random index number between 100 and 9999999
    clone.html(function (index, html) {
        var rndIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999999) + 100);
        return html.replace(new RegExp('%%index%%','g'),rndIndex);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One trick I've seen used for this is to put a hidden field before each checkbox that submits the same field with a value of 0. That way, if you check the checkbox it will overwrite the 0 value with the checkbox value, but if you don't, you'll get a 0 for unchecked instead of nothing in your data.

The answer from the comments of keeping a running total of indexes could work, too, but is a bit more complicated depending on how and when the DOM can be modified.

Comment: I came accross this solution, but it wouldn't work in this case since I use non-indexed arrays. Both fields are submitted when the checkbox is checked.